# Sveltekit using {value} inside @html generated HTML

Tags: sveltekit

I want to create a Table component, just for the data it works fine but I want also to create dynamic Tags for Edit/Delete and so on.

My Code looks like this:

```
<script>
    
    const data = [
        {
            username: "Test 1"
        },
        {
            username: "Test 2"
        },
        {
            username: "Test 3"
        },
        {
            username: "Test 4"
        },
    ]
    
    const headers = [
        {
            key: 'username',
            text: 'Username'
        },
        {
            key: null,
            text: 'Reset Link',
            field: '<p>/users/reset/{user.username}</p>'
        }
    ];

</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        {#each headers as header}
            <th>{header.text}</th>
        {/each}
    </tr>

    {#each data as user}
        <tr>
            {#each headers as header}
                {#if user[header.key]}
                    <td>{user[header.key]}</td>
                {:else}
                    <td>{@html header.field}</td>
                {/if}
            {/each}
        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/5495b8e0aaa8407dacb0da9bd173f88e

And the output looks like this:

```
Username    Reset Link
Test 1          /users/reset/{user.username}
Test 2          /users/reset/{user.username}
Test 3          /users/reset/{user.username}
Test 4          /users/reset/{user.username}
```

I would expect an output like this:

```
Username    Reset Link
Test 1          /users/reset/Test 1
Test 2          /users/reset/Test 2
Test 3          /users/reset/Test 3
Test 4          /users/reset/Test 4
```

So how can I add these dynamic fields?

Comment: You should *avoid* `{@html}`, one rarely should need it at all. If used, you have to make sure to protect against XSS.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. I already changed it to another Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks José for you Input, with your information I changed the Code like this:

Added a new simple "Table Link" Component:

```
<script>
  export let text;
  export let basicLink;

  const modifiedLink = `${basicLink}/${text}`;
</script>

<a href={modifiedLink}>{text}</a>
```

Which is now added into the loop:

```
{#each headers as header}
  {#if user[header.key]}
    <td style={header.style}>{user[header.key]}</td>
  {:else}
    <td style={header.style}><TableLink basicLink={header.field} text={user['username']} /></td>
  {/if}
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want Svelte to automagically recognize that you have written Sveltescript (hehe) into a string, and simply evaluate it as such.  That won't work.

If you are trying to create a table component that allows for dynamic/arbitrary column content, you should use `<slot>` elements; if you are not trying to do this, just hardcode this link inside the markup.  For example:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        {#each headers as header}
            <th>{header.text}</th>
        {/each}
    </tr>

    {#each data as user}
        <tr>
            {#each headers as header}
                <td>
                    {@const value = user[header.key]}
                    {#if value}
                        {value}
                    {:else}
                        <p>/users/reset/{user.username}</p>
                    {/if}
                </td>
            {/each}
        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>
```

If you would like to see a generic table component with `<slot>`'ed columns, check [this one](https://github.com/webJose/svelte-htable) out.